# SSRS report deployment

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I have 3 server, web server, app server and db server. Where should I place  the report url and report datasource in ? currently I placing in the web which is not working right now. Please help. Thanks.

The web server cannot directly go through app server. It block by the firewall and only allow by calling using the wcf request. The SSRS install in db server but the physical report is place in the app server that point to db server virtual directory. The report deployment is using the SSDT at the app server.

Comment: You're going to have to give us more to go on. Can you define "not working"? And where is SSRS installed? On the web server?

Comment: Is your app server perhaps where ssrs is installed?

Comment: update the details as above.